# RecyclerView is crashing after fast scrolling and calling API onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
public class FragmentPatientsByVital extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Patient> mList;
    private AdapterVitalPatient mAdapter;
    private MultiStateToggleButton mMultiStateToggleButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patient_by_vital, container, false);
        initUi(v);

        if (mList != null)
            updateList(mList);

        return v;
    }

    private void initUi(View v) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mMultiStateToggleButton = (MultiStateToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.mstb_multi_id);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mMultiStateToggleButton.setOnValueChangedListener(new ToggleButton.OnValueChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChanged(int position) {
                mAdapter.filterBy(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<Patient> mList) {
        if (mList == null) return;
        this.mList = mList;

        if (mAdapter == null)
            mAdapter = new AdapterVitalPatient(mList);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static FragmentPatientsByVital newIntance() {
        FragmentPatientsByVital f = new FragmentPatientsByVital();
        return f;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterVitalPatient extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterVitalPatient.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Patient> mList;

    public AdapterVitalPatient(ArrayList<Patient> mList) {
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(InjectUtils.getInflator().inflate(R.layout.adapter_vital_patient, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Patient p = mList.get(position);
        holder.mNameTextView.setText(p.getName());

        if (mList.get(position).getSummary() != null) {
            holder.updateRecords(mList.get(position).getSummary());
        } else {
            try {
                holder.callApi(p.getEmail(), position);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public void filterBy(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:             //!--- Any

                break;

            case 1:             //!--- Normal

                break;

            case 2:             //!--- High
                break;

            case 3:             //!--- Low
                break;

        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView mNameTextView;
        private final ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private final GridLayout mTableLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            mTableLayout = (GridLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
        }

        public void callApi(String email, final int pos) {

            try {
                RahaDelegates api = InjectUtils.getNetworkObj().create(RahaDelegates.class);
                Call<String> call = api.getLatestVitals(String.format(RahaDelegates.GET_LATEST_VITALS, email));
                InjectUtils.getNetworkClient().callApi(call, new ApiInterface() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(boolean result, String completeResponse) {

                        Type token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Vital>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setSummary((ArrayList<Vital>) InjectUtils.getGsonObj().fromJson(completeResponse, token));
                        updateRecords(mList.get(pos).getSummary());
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void updateRecords(ArrayList<Vital> details) {
            mTableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTableLayout.removeAllViews();

                for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("List Size", String.valueOf(details.size()));
                    Vital v = details.get(i);
                    if (!v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("lungreco") && !v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("kickco")) {
                        View view = InjectUtils.getInflator().inflate(R.layout.adapter_home_vital_patient, mTableLayout, false);
                        mTableLayout.addView(view);
                        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vital_name);
                        TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vital_value);
                        name.setText(v.getVitalName());

                        if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("bodyc")) {
                            value.setText(v.getFat() + "/" + v.getMuscale() + " " + v.getUnit());
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("temp")) {
                            if (v.getValue() != null) {
                                value.setText(Math.round(Float.valueOf(v.getValue())) + " " + v.getUnit());
                            }
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("heartra")) {
                            value.setText(v.getValue());
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("etalbe")) {
                            value.setText(v.getValue() + " " + v.getUnit());
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("bloodpres")) {
                            value.setText(v.getSystolic() + "/" + v.getDiastolic() + " " + v.getUnit());
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("loodoxy")) {
                            value.setText(v.getValue() + " " + v.getUnit());
                        } else if (v.getVitalName().toLowerCase().contains("oodglucos")) {
                            value.setText(v.getValue() + " " + v.getUnit());
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

```
02-10 09:06:39.430 1600-1600/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
02-10 09:06:39.476 16831-17154/? E/AndroidCll-SettingsSync: Could not get or parse settings
02-10 09:06:39.547 16831-17062/? E/Appboy v2.5.0 .bo.app.cj: Received server error from request: invalid_api_key
02-10 09:06:39.547 16831-17062/? E/Appboy v2.5.0 .bo.app.ci: Error occurred while executing Braze request: invalid_api_key
02-10 09:06:39.603 16831-17154/? E/AndroidCll-SettingsSync: Could not get or parse settings
02-10 09:06:39.759 1600-1600/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
02-10 09:06:41.294 16594-16594/sa.digitrends.rahah.doctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sa.digitrends.rahah.doctor, PID: 16594
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
        at sa.digitrends.doctor.adapter.AdapterVitalPatient$ViewHolder.updateRecords(AdapterVitalPatient.java:125)
        at sa.digitrends.doctor.adapter.AdapterVitalPatient$ViewHolder$1.onResponse(AdapterVitalPatient.java:106)
        at sa.app.base.retrofit.client.NetworkClient$1.onResponse(NetworkClient.java:60)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
02-10 09:06:41.761 16831-16831/? E/Referral: (LauncherApplication.java:890) restarted
```

Comment: You should call api other than onbindviewholder ().. as Api takes extra time to fetch data  ... in this time view crashes.  if you are calling api via some library like volley then it calls api in second thread that not able to join on calling function, it seems to null pointer exception as data is fetched late after execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove below code segment from `onBindView` and add it inside another method that needs to fire when user do that relevant action

```
if (mList.get(position).getSummary() != null) {
        holder.updateRecords(mList.get(position).getSummary());
    } else {
        try {
            holder.callApi(p.getEmail(), position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

then you can do `notifydatasetchanged` after get success response inside that `public void onResponse(boolean result, String completeResponse)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have server error

**Appboy v2.5.0 .bo.app.cj: Received server error from request: invalid_api_key 02-10 09:06:39.547 16831-17062/? E/Appboy v2.5.0 .bo.app.ci: Error occurred while executing Braze request: invalid_api_key 02-10 09:06:39.603 16831-17154**

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
```

Update `updateRecords` methods as below

```
public void updateRecords(@Nullable ArrayList<Vital> details) {
   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   if(details == null) {
      return;  
   }
   . . .
   . . .
   . . .
}
```

In general there can be further improvement made.

- Avoid making API calls directly from Fragments or any Classes having views
- Parse response in background thread. Below code might block your main thread for long time, when response is huge.

```
InjectUtils.getGsonObj().fromJson(completeResponse, token)
```